# Is a bitwise OR and AND NOT the same as addition and subtraction when a set is known?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

If `a = 2` and `b = 4` where `a OR b = 6` and `(a|b) AND NOT b = a` then is a bitwise `AND NOT` equivalent to subtraction when the the value is a set of flags which is known to include the flag being removed?

Is it the same for addition as well?

Note that this is in a situation where the flags are known to exist in the set. No addition or subtraction would occur if the flag is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're asking, yes. So:

- If `(a & b) == 0`, then `(a | b) == (a + b)`, and
- If `(a | b) == a`, then `(a & ~b) == (a - b)`

As a sort of proof, take that addition can be written as `a + b == (a ^ b) + ((a & b) << 1)` (which is doing all the sums-without-carry, and then adding the carries separately). So if `a & b` is zero, the carries disappear and it becomes just `a ^ b`, and that in turn becomes `a | b`. A similar thing happens with the subtraction where we know there are no borrows.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you're ORing with values whose 1-bits definitely *are not*  in the first operand or ANDing with bit-negated values of values whose 1-bits definitely *are* in the first operand.